# jquery display formatted json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, format

Hi i have a problem becouse my json isn't display as formatted json.

in my web page i have a `<pre></pre>` tag, it cointains json string:

json example:

```
{"status": "OK", "output": {"pools": [{"stats": {"bytes_used": 0, "objects": 0, "kb_used": 0}, "name": "data", "id": 0}, {"stats": {"bytes_used": 0, "objects": 0, "kb_used": 0}, "name": "metadata", "id": 1}, {"stats": {"bytes_used": 0, "objects": 0, "kb_used": 0}, "name": "rbd", "id": 2}], "stats": {"total_used": 63330648, "total_space": 125604864, "total_avail": 62274216}}}
```

i use jquery script to format it:

```
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify($(this).text(), null, '\t');
$(this).text(jsonPretty);
```

but itsn not working the result is:

```
"{\"status\": \"OK\", \"output\": {\"pools\": [{\"stats\": {\"bytes_used\": 0, \"objects\": 0, \"kb_used\": 0}, \"name\": \"data\", \"id\": 0}, {\"stats\": {\"bytes_used\": 0, \"objects\": 0, \"kb_used\": 0}, \"name\": \"metadata\", \"id\": 1}, {\"stats\": {\"bytes_used\": 0, \"objects\": 0, \"kb_used\": 0}, \"name\": \"rbd\", \"id\": 2}], \"stats\": {\"total_used\": 63330648, \"total_space\": 125604864, \"total_avail\": 62274216}}}"
```

how can i format it to display nice formatted json ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` takes an object, but you are passing it a string.  To use this approach, you would need to turn your string into an object then back into a string:

http://jsfiddle.net/yEez8/

```
var jsonStr = $("pre").text();
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\t');

$("pre").text(jsonPretty);
```