# How to output JSON with spaces and new lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried:

```
$("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(dataArray, null, '\t'));
```

But the output is:

> [ { "20": "10", "Barcellona": "Cagliari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti"
>   }, { "20": "15", "Barcellona": "Sassari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti"
>   }, { "20": "22", "Barcellona": "Torino", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" }
>   ]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858700/1018804) on SO is perfect but I tried to apply it but did not manage it, this is the jsFiddle to play with:

```js
$(function () {
    var csv = $("#fileUpload").val();

    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\r\n");

                    if(rows.length>0){
                        var firstRowCells = GetCSVCells(rows[0], ",");

                        var dataArray = new Array();
                        for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
                        {
                            var cells = GetCSVCells(rows[i], ",");
                            var obj = {};
                            for(var j=0;j<cells.length;j++)
                            {
                                obj[firstRowCells[j]] = cells[j];
                            }
                            dataArray.push(obj);
                        }

                        $("#dvCSV").html('');
                        $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(dataArray, null, '\t'));
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});

function GetCSVCells(row, separator){
    return row.split(separator);
}
```

```css
#heading { font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; }
.text { width: 99%; height: 200px; }
.small { font-size: small; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
  <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" name="upload"/>
  <hr />
<div id="dvCSV"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you append this to a HTML element, you need something like e.g. set it's `white-space` to `pre-wrap` for it to wrap properly.

Stack snippet

```js
var arr = [ { "20": "10", "Barcellona": "Cagliari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" }, { "20": "15", "Barcellona": "Sassari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" }, { "20": "22", "Barcellona": "Torino", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" } ];

document.getElementById('dvCSV').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, null, '\t');
```

```css
#dvCSV {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<div id="dvCSV"></div>
```

Comment: oooh that's what it was! The css!! Didn't think about it, yes it works fine now. Will accept as soon as it let me

Answer (score 1):

It works fine [with spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), like:

```
JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  '); // Using 2 spaces as the 'space' argument
```

```js
var arr = [ { "20": "10", "Barcellona": "Cagliari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" }, { "20": "15", "Barcellona": "Sassari", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" }, { "20": "22", "Barcellona": "Torino", "Dipendenti": "Dipendenti" } ];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  '));
```

Comment: mm tried `var arr = (dataArray);
                        $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  '));` with no luck, dataArray is an array if that helps

Comment: Upvoting because even though it doesn't address the question (formatting readable JSON within HTML), it is also nice to point out that the same effect can be done within the console.